# Prove that the set $H = \{ \lambda_{a} | a \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $S_{G}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

2. $G$ is a group (whose operation we will denote by juxtaposition)
   and suppose that a is some fixed element of $G$. Let $\lambda_{a} : G \to G$ be the
   function defined by $\lambda_{a}(x) = ax$ for all $x \in G$. Prove that $\lambda_{a}$ is a bijection. (In
   other words, prove that $\lambda_{a}$ is a permutation of $G$.)

I have already finish this part, and I need help for question 3

3. Suppose that $G$ is a group and that for each element $a \in G$ the function
   $\lambda_{a} : G \to G$ is as defined in problem 2. Recall that we have defined $S_{G}$ to be
   the set of all permutations of $G$. Prove that the set $H = \{ \lambda_{a} | a \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $S_{G}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_{G}$, you need to show three things:

1) The identity permutation is in $H$. Can you think of a natural candidate? (What happens when you left multiply any element of $G$ by $e$?)

2) The product (composition) of any two elements of $H$ is an element of $H$. What happens when you compose $\lambda_{a}$ with $\lambda_{b}$ for some $a, b \in G$? Can you write the resulting map in terms of a map that should be in $H$?

3) Every element of $H$ has an inverse in $H$. What is the natural candidate for the inverse of the map $\lambda_{a}$? (If you left multiply by $a$ for some fixed $a \in G$, can you left multiply by something else to 'undo' the left multiplication by $a$? Identify this as a permutation which is an element of $H$).

Comment: got you, but how I write for these question?